# nginx service can't run

Tags: nginx, server

After typing service nginx start on my server text below appears:

**Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks for any information and help given. bless you.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #Ustaw limity połączeń. Layer-7 Security Julek
    #limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;
    #limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

    # INCLUDE ALL WEBSITE
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/bialogardzianin.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/vigilance.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/envigilance.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/kasacja-aut.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/mahulaboni.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/kowalewscy.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/playstories.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/odnovit-centrum.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/lzs.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/alpha.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/testvigi.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/malinowskafashion.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/tarasewicz.conf;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # #Buffers
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    ## GZIP
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    # Cache most accessed static files
    open_file_cache          max=100000 inactive=360m;
    open_file_cache_valid    2m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;

    ## Hide the Nginx version number.
    server_tokens off;

    ## Fill in with your own resolver.
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    ## Timeouts.
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: `vps345829 nginx[2171]: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("/etc/nginx/cert/trustchain.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/cert/trustchain.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib)
 vps345829 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 vps345829 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
vps345829 systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.`

Comment: You are missing the `etc/nginx/cert/trustchain.crt` file